# How can I select a specific color from matplotlib colormaps?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib as plt
import seaborn as sns
pallete = sns.color_palette("tab10", 3)
```

In python, this gives the first three colors from the tab10 colormaps. How can I use the other colors? For example, instead of using the first three colors of tab10, I want to use the 1st, 2nd and 4th one. Or, I want to use the 1st, 6th and 8th one. Is it possible? Thank you for your kind concern.

[image]

Comment: You can assign the color palette you want to use to a variable and use the index to use the color of your choice. `my_color = sns.color_palette("tab10", 10);my_color[0];(0.12156862745098039, 0.4666666666666667, 0.7058823529411765)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seaborn's palettes are represented as lists of rgb values. You can use these lists to create a new palette. For example:

```py
import seaborn as sns

palette_tab10 = sns.color_palette("tab10", 10)
palette = sns.color_palette([palette_tab10[0], palette_tab10[1], palette_tab10[3]])
```

```py
sns.palplot(palette_tab10)
```

[image: seaborn palette tab10]

```py
sns.palplot(palette)
```

[image: seaborn tab10 1st,2nd,4th]

To obtain a matplotlib colormap, add `as_cmap=True`:

```
cmap = sns.color_palette([palette_tab10[0], palette_tab10[1], palette_tab10[3]], as_cmap=True)
```

Seaborn also allows to just provide a list of colors as the palette parameter, e.g.:

```py
sns.palplot(['DeepSkyBlue', palette_tab10[3], 'Chartreuse'])
```

[image: palette as list of colors]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, take a slice from a palette, like this:

`palette = sns.color_palette("tab20b")[4:7]`

This will return the green shades from `tab20b`.

```
palette = [(0.38823529411764707, 0.4745098039215686, 0.2235294117647059),
 (0.5490196078431373, 0.6352941176470588, 0.3215686274509804),
 (0.7098039215686275, 0.8117647058823529, 0.4196078431372549)]
```